# What will Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1); do

Tags: javascript, html, function, random, var

I came across the following command:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
```

I understand that `Math.floor()` will convert to the lowest integer, but what does `Math.random() * 10 + 1` do?

Comment: you only need to know what `Math.random()` does ... the `* 10 + 1` is elementary level maths - when in doubt [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: `Math.random() * 10 + 1` generates a random number between ( 0 - 10 ) + 1

Comment: `Math.random()` will return a float `0 - 0.99999999` (less than 1) so `* 10` is  `0 to 9.999999` then `+ 1` is `1 to 10.99999999`, and rounded down is `1 to 10`

Answer (score 4):

`Math.random` returns a floating point number `x` such that:

[image]

Multiplying `10` to `x` yields a floating point number in the range:

[image]

And then adding `1` to `10x` yields a floating point number in the range:

[image]

And finally flooring `10x + 1` yields an **integer** in the range:

[image]

**Therefore, `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)` yields an integer that lies in the range `[1, 10]`.**

Comment: `evaluates to a number...` should probably be `evaluates to an integer....`

Comment: @MikeMat Yeah nice observation, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Math.random generates a random number between 0 and 1. So for example it can be .124 or .42242. When you multiply this random number against something, you are basically making it so that the new result is no less than 0, but no more than the number you are multiplying it against.

So in your example, you are multiplying it against 10, which means you will get a random number between 0 and 10 with decimals; technically this range is 'more than 0, but less than 10'. The +1 just increases the total range so that it is between 1 and 11, or 'more than 1, but less than 11.

When you apply Math.floor() to this, you are rounding all of these results down. So in the case without the '+1', your finite range is actually 0-9, and with the +1 it is 1-10

Comment: Keep in mind that any time you do the 'Math.floor(Math.random()*num)' that whatever your num is means your range is 0-num not including num.

So when you add something to that, you are increasing both the start and end of the range.